# How to handle huge data from a REST service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

We are using a REST service that returns huge data.
In production, the server hardware can handle it.
I need to test the REST service by getting the data on my local machine,
which cannot handle the huge data.
My local machine is a 4G i5.
I am getting out of memory exception every time I hit the service.

`response.getStatus()`  returns 200 status.
But while collecting the data using input stream reader, I get an out of memory exception.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(newByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));
```

Is there any other way to collect the data without hitting the memory exception?

I tried pushing my VM size to 2G but, it still doesn't work.

Comment: How about returning only part of the response?

Comment: write to disk or to /dev/null

Comment: @Petey I need the byet's array for writing into file, but while getting the bytes it fails 'response.getEntity().getBytes()'

Comment: @LutzHorn, You mean altering the web service to return in parts or while receiving the response we can split it into parts?

Comment: Consider adding a "test mode" to your REST service that either writes the response data to a file or returns only a fraction of the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the service supports it, use the HTTP standard approach of [requesting chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954894/hidden-features-of-http/2824172#2824172) within the range of the entire response content payload.

Another approach (again, assuming the API supports it) is [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776448/pagination-in-a-rest-web-application).

Comment: This is a good approach that I can recommend. Thank you Brian!!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a threshold setting in the REST service configuration that limits the amount of data returned.
In production, the threshold would either not be set or would be set to a large value.
In your test environment, you can set the threshold to a small, managable value.